# Android, replace YouTubePlayerFragment onInitializationFailure()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-youtube-api

In my Android application I have placed a `YouTubePlayerFragment` inside another `Fragment` via a `FrameLayout` which I simply add the `Youtubeplayer` into.
This all works as intended.
Now, in case the the phone has no Youtube App installed which is required for the Youtube API to run, I do not want to add the `YouTubePlayerFragment` via a `FragmentTransaction` to the root Fragment.

What I thought of was simply creating a `boolean youtubeSuccess` and set it to true, and if `onInitializationFailure` gets called I set it to false.  So later on I can simply use this:

```
....
    if (youtubeSuccess) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        }
        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
.....
```

But somehow my code does not work, and I still get the error message displayed: [image]

Now I don't know if i don't understand the lifecycle correctly or if I am to blind to find the obvious mistake. If, why does youtubeSuccess never gets set ?

Full code:

```
public class SampleYouTubeSlide extends Fragment {

    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private static final String ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId";
    private int layoutResId;
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    static boolean youtubeSuccess;


    public SampleYouTubeSlide() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    public static SampleYouTubeSlide newInstance(int layoutResId) {
        SampleYouTubeSlide sampleSlide = new SampleYouTubeSlide();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId);
        sampleSlide.setArguments(args);

        return sampleSlide;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID))
            layoutResId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

               youtubeSuccess = true;

                if (!wasRestored) {
                    YPlayer = player;
                    YPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
                    //YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                    YPlayer.cueVideo(getResources().getString(R.string.instructionsVideoId), 1);
                    //YPlayer.loadVideo(getResources().getString(R.string.instructionsVideoId));
                    //YPlayer.play();

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // Called when initialization of the player fails.
                youtubeSuccess = false;

            }


        });

        if (youtubeSuccess) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        }

        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
    }

}
```